# angular ng-class with two classes, one from a variable name and one with condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I a m a little stuck with a problem, probably some syntax I can't find on the internet.

I created an angular directive that receives a class name as a scope variable.
In the tamplate I want to add the given classname and another class as conditional.
something like that:

```
app.directive('MyDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            className: '=',
        },
        template: "<div ng-class="className, 'otherClass':{expression}"></div>"
    }
});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `className` is a property on the scope:

You could make use of array expression with object literal syntax itself.

```
 <div ... ng-class="[className, {true : 'otherClass'}[expression]]"
```

or mix it with `class`

```
<div ... class="{{className}}" ng-class="{'otherClass': expression}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
change your code like this
    app.directive('MyDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            className: '=',
        },
        template: "<div ng-class="'className':true, 'otherClass':    {expression}"></div>"
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use by your scope data with some condition or expression.

```
<div ng-class="{'{{item.name}}' : item.condition}">
```

or

```
<div ng-class="$variableToEvaluate ? '{{item.nameiftrue}}' : '{{item.nameiffalse}}'">
```